# Convert class to module Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, functional-programming

I have a basic `scrapy` class that spiders a website.

I simply want to convert it to only using `functions` instead of a `class-oop` structure.

How can I do this?

```
import scrapy
class BrickSetSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "my_spider"
    site_search_url = 'website.com'
    base = 'http://www.website.com/search'
    start_urls = [base + str(site_search_url)]
    '''method1 - parse page urls'''
    def method1():
        #code1
    '''method2 - parse urls on the page from method1'''
    def method2():
        #code2
```

Specifically, I am not sure how to instantiate the `scrapy.Spider` parameter portion in a `functional` way, instead of `oop`

Thank you.

Comment: Why would you like to do that?

Comment: Im more familiar with it.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a brief overview of what the methods do and how the are called / call each other.

Comment: @BluCode - please see comments on each method

Comment: @omri_saadon - thanks, yes I know that. Is `functional` not feasible using `scrapy` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. `Spider` is an abstract class, which only implements a called `start_requests()`. This method calls other functions that you must implemented in your own classes. You either have to subclass it, or see if some other class already does in the library. See *template method* design pattern.